# jBPM Persistence: Unable to build EntityManagerFactory

Tags: hibernate, jbpm

I am trying to make my jBPM Project persistent. Therefore I used the this [tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.2/userguide/ch07.html).
At first I imported all the additional jars needed (according to the website). 
I also added `mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar` because I want to use mysql as persistent storage.

After that I added the "stateful" code to my project:

```
KnowledgeBase kbase = readKnowledgeBase(name);
StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = null;
JBPMHelper.startH2Server();
JBPMHelper.setupDataSource();
if(ProcessManager.sessionId == -1){
    ksession = JBPMHelper.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(kbase);
    ProcessManager.sessionId = ksession.getId();
}
else {
ksession = JBPMHelper.loadStatefulKnowledgeSession(
    kbase,
    ProcessManager.sessionId);
}
```

Then I added to `resources/META-INF` the file `jBPM.properties`:

> persistence.datasource.name=jdbc/jbpm-ds
>
> persistence.datasource.user=test
>
> persistence.datasource.password=test
>
> persistence.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/helpme
>
> persistence.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>
> persistence.enabled=true
>
> persistence.persistenceunit.name=org.jbpm.persistence.jpa
>
> persistence.persistenceunit.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

If I now run the project there is always the following exception (on `ksession = JBPMHelper.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(kbase);`):

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: org.jbpm.persistence.jpa] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find datasource
>
> Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my Problem. Normally the `JBPMHelper` loads the jBPM directly from the [jar](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-test/src/main/java/org/jbpm/test/JBPMHelper.java):

```
public static Properties getProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties
            .load(JBPMHelper.class.getResourceAsStream("/jBPM.properties"));
    } catch (Throwable t) {
    // do nothing, use defaults
    }

    return properties;
}
```

I replaced the loading Mechanism and now it is loading the `jBPM.properties` correctly:

```
public static Properties getProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        InputStream input
            = new FileInputStream("./resources/META-INF/jBPM.properties");
        properties.load(input);
        System.out.println("RPOP"+properties.toString());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
    // do nothing, use defaults
    }

    return properties;
}
```

(My answer adapted from BartoszKP - thanks)