# jBPM6.3+Hibernate4+Tomcat7+JPA2.0Exception: Unable to build EntityManagerFactory

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa, tomcat7, jbpm

I was trying to make [this](https://developer.jboss.org/people/bpmn2user/blog/2013/12/27/jbpm6--tomcat-7--web-example) example work for me. Since my jbpm version is 6.3.0.Final, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489713/jbpm-persistence-unable-to-build-entitymanagerfactory) solution absolutely won't solve my problem.

My scenario is, firstly, I created a JPA & Dynamic Web Project by using Eclipse Mars1, and copied all the example files into my new project, then modified TaskProcessServlet.java, as shown below, because of the obsoleteness and deprecation of the `Runtime`part in original servlet code. When I built my project and ran on independent Tomcat 7.0.64 other than server inside of Eclipse, and jsp showed up without any problem, but when I clicked `create Process`which will fire the TaskProcessServlet, I got an error message:

```
Error:[PersistenceUnit: org.jbpm.persistence.jpa] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
```

Would my postgresql-9.4.1207.jar(for Tomcat8) be a problem? I don't think so because I kept getting same error in Tomcat 8, so I downgrade my Tomcat from 8.0.30 to Tomcat 7.0.64.

I'm able to run jbpm-console from JBOSS both on my Tomcat 8 and 7. Does this jbpm-console interfere my project?

How to tackle this problem?

Any idea would be appreciated, thank you very much.

Software Environment:

```
Ubuntu 64-bit 14.04
Eclipse Mars1
jBPM 6.3.0.Final
PostgreSQL 9.3(postgresql-9.4.1207.jar)
Hibernate 4.2.21.Final
JPA 2.0
Tomcat 7.0.64
NO Spring
NO Maven
```

TaskProcessServlet.java

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {
            String action = request.getParameter("action");

        if (action.equals("CreateProcess")) {

               /*
                UserTransaction ut = (UserTransaction) new InitialContext().lookup( "java:comp/UserTransaction" );
               ut.begin();


                *
                 * Get the local task service
                 *
                KieSession ksession = JBPMUtil.getSingletonSession();
                TaskService taskService = JBPMUtil.getTaskService();




                ksession.startProcess("com.autopal.bpmn.sampleHTformvariables",params); 
                 System.out.println(" after start");
                //ksession.fireAllRules();
                ut.commit();
                */

                // create the entity manager factory
                EntityManagerFactory emf = EntityManagerFactoryManager.get().getOrCreate("org.jbpm.persistence.jpa");
                TransactionManager tm = TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager();

                // setup the runtime environment
                RuntimeEnvironment environment = RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.Factory.get()
                .newDefaultBuilder()
                .addAsset(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("taskexample/SampleHumanTaskFormVariables.bpmn"), ResourceType.BPMN2)
                    .addEnvironmentEntry(EnvironmentName.TRANSACTION_MANAGER, tm)
                    .get();

                // get the kie session
                RuntimeManager manager = RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get().newPerRequestRuntimeManager(environment);
                RuntimeEngine runtime = manager.getRuntimeEngine(ProcessInstanceIdContext.get());
                KieSession ksession = runtime.getKieSession();

                // start the transaction
                UserTransaction ut = InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
                ut.begin();
                Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                params.put("priority", "High");
                params.put("modelNumber", "123"); 
                params.put("quantity", "66");
                // perform multiple commands inside one transaction
                ksession.startProcess("com.autopal.bpmn.sampleHTformvariables",params);

                // commit the transaction
                ut.commit();                    



                request.setAttribute("message", "Process Created!");
                RequestDispatcher rD = request.getRequestDispatcher("adminuser.jsp");
                rD.forward(request, response);
            }
            ...
```

persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="org.jbpm.persistence.jpa" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/jbpm-ds</jta-data-source>

<mapping-file>META-INF/JBPMorm.xml</mapping-file>
<mapping-file>META-INF/Taskorm.xml</mapping-file>
<mapping-file>META-INF/Executor-orm.xml</mapping-file>
<mapping-file>META-INF/Servicesorm.xml</mapping-file>
<mapping-file>META-INF/TaskAuditorm.xml</mapping-file>

<class>org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.ProcessInstanceInfo</class>
<class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>
<class>org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo</class>

<class>org.jbpm.process.audit.ProcessInstanceLog</class>
<class>org.jbpm.process.audit.NodeInstanceLog</class>
<class>org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog</class>

<class>org.jbpm.persistence.correlation.CorrelationKeyInfo</class>
<class>org.jbpm.persistence.correlation.CorrelationPropertyInfo</class>

<!-- manager -->
<class>org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.jpa.ContextMappingInfo</class>

<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.AttachmentImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.ContentImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.BooleanExpressionImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.CommentImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.DeadlineImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.DelegationImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.EscalationImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.GroupImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.I18NTextImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.NotificationImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.EmailNotificationImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.EmailNotificationHeaderImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.PeopleAssignmentsImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.ReassignmentImpl</class>

<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.TaskImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.TaskDataImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.UserImpl</class>

<!--BAM for task service -->
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.audit.impl.model.BAMTaskSummaryImpl</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.jndi.class" value="bitronix.tm.jndi.BitronixInitialContextFactory"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.BitronixJtaPlatform"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Catalina.out

```
    INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.connection.password=****, c3p0.numHelperThreads=10, c3p0.maxIdleTime=60, c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true, c3p0.maxStatements=100, hibernate.show_sql=true, hibernate.default_catalog=mybox, hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=100, c3p0.maxPoolSize=30, c3p0.initialPoolSize=3, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create, hibernate.default_schema=public, hibernate.connection.release_mode=after_transaction, hibernate.connection.username=postgres, c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod=900, hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.postgresql.Driver, c3p0.minPoolSize=2, c3p0.preferredTestQuery=select now(), c3p0.acquireIncrement=3, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.80:5432/mybox}
Feb 05, 2016 3:58:09 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Feb 05, 2016 3:58:10 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: META-INF/JBPMorm.xml
Feb 05, 2016 3:58:10 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: META-INF/Taskorm.xml
Feb 05, 2016 3:58:10 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: META-INF/Executor-orm.xml
Feb 05, 2016 3:58:10 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: META-INF/Servicesorm.xml
Feb 05, 2016 3:58:10 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: META-INF/TaskAuditorm.xml
```

Comment: I've tried change `postgresql-9.4.1207.jar`  to  `postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.jar`, still the same problem. BTW, as to catalinal.out, TaskProcessServlet was stuck there, that was the last line of my tomcat log.

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace around your original error "Unable to build EntityManagerFactory" ? There usually is a hint of what's going on. Two notes by the way: 1) You are not passing EMF to the RuntimeEnvironment. 2) You should create one RuntimeManager for one deployment - not one RuntimeManager for *every new process* - this operation is very pricy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Anton Giertli, Thank you for your attention.

I've solved this problem after modifying my server.xml and adding a hibernate.cfg.xml for JPA by referring to [here](https://ironclaws.wordpress.com/2012/06/12/jpbm52tomcat7h2demo/).

But I still had consequential issues that I need to figure out.

Thank you any way.